# Keycloak access token gets invalid even before the Access Token life span gets expired

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, keycloak-angular

i am using keycloak in my client application for Authentication and Authorization purpose. I configured the keycloak Tokens under Relams settings as below

> SSO Session Idle - 8 - Hours
>
> SSO Session Max  - 10 - Hours
>
> Access Token Lifespan - 5 - Minutes
>
> Access Token Lifespan For Implicit Flow  - 15 - Minutes
>
> Client Session Idle  - 0 Minutes
>
> Client Session Max  - 0 Minutes

Since the life span of the Access token is 5 minutes, my assumption is that the token i am using in client app should be valid for 5 minutes of duration, But the token is expiring even before this 5 minutes of time. (exactly after 4minutes 15 seconds).

when i try to access any of the backend APIs, the validation fails with an error as below

> WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="An
> error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Jwt expired at
> 2023-06-01T13:09:09Z",
> error_uri="https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750#section-3.1"

why are the tokens getting invalid even before the expiry duration ? and how to resolve this ?

Comment: Have you figured this out @Lisa ? I'm having the exact same issue!

Comment: @Zeon No , I could not figured out the root cause. Fortunately my system admin restarted the system where the keycloak server is running , there after i did not notice this issue